# map rails root path to external https url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to redirect to my root path on some specific url. For example i have following into my routes.rb

```
root "home#index"
```

And when I run rails server and open it on browser then I want my to redirect on https://example.com instead of http://localhost:3000. Please help me if it is possible.
I have tries with `root "home#index", to: redirect('https://example.com')` 
but this did not work.

Comment: First of all, which web server are you using and have you bought a domain which you are speaking of ? if you are done with the domain name, then you can configure you web server for example: Nginx, with the domain name setting on your hosted server.

If you want to just host in you localmachine, for example in ubuntu. go to /etc/hosts file and add 127.0.0.1 some.example.com

Then restart your rails server and then try, it should map to the content written in the hosts file.

Comment: Do you ask about deploying your app on that domain? `localhost` vs `example.com` is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `root to: redirect('http://example.com/')`

Comment: Looks like OP might use word "redirect" not in a meaning that we a used to and it is not clear if the question is about either deploying their app or https redirect. (just in case: it was not me who downvoted)

Comment: Could be, but to me it seems clear that he wants to redirect the root url, so it's done how I answered. The way the author used the redirect was not correct, so I added the correct way, that's why I don't understand the downvote.